# Sparse matrix with fast access

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

While working with large SciPy CSR sparse matrices I noticed that slicing the matrix to get a single row from the matrix was very slow as it seems to make a copy.

Is there any way to make a sparse matrix that takes a reference of the existing row instead of copying it, perhaps there is a more fitting implementation than CSR matrix?

What I need for my implementation is fast lookup for elements and rows and fast lookup of all non zero indices of a vector. I never need to change the matrix in any way or perform other operations on the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the CSR representation to slice the underlying arrays directly and share the data with a new CSR matrix:

```
mat = # some CSR matrix
i = # the index of whatever row you want
start, stop = mat.indptr[i], mat.indptr[i+1]
noncopy_row_i = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((mat.data[start:stop],
                                         mat.indices[start:stop],
                                         numpy.array([0, stop-start])),
                                        shape=(1, mat.shape[1]))
```

Comment: I tested your function against `mat[i,:]`.  Timings are 69.3 µs v 107 µs, a modest improvement.  Indexing on a `lil` format is 78 µs.

Comment: If you use your code to return just the `data` and `indices`, and not construct a new `csr_matrix`, it is much faster, on the order of 2 µs.  Same speedup applies when extracting the `row` elements for the `lil` format.

Comment: I decided to do just that, only use indices and not construct a new csr_matrix. Managed to get my algorithm to run in around 10 micro seconds instead of 1 miliseconds in total with these optimizations which is good enough for now, thank you both of you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Numpy supports  different types os sparces matrices: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html#usage-information

May be `coo_matrix` will give faster elements lookup, but also you can loose on some other operations. I think the best way is to benchmark on your data and algorythms.

Comment: If you need nonzero elements there's a special `nonzero` method - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.nonzero

Comment: That sparse `nonzero` method essentially returns the `row` and `col` attributes of the `coo` format.  Check it's source code.